# How to display a marked-up string without the markup?

Tags: latex, text-properties

**Q:** how can I display a marked-up string without the markup?

I have a string with LaTeX markup, such as the following name with
an umlaut:

```
Tezc\"ur
```

I want to display the string in a buffer without the markup, but
with the umlaut, as in:

```
Tezcür
```

How can I *display* the string as intended without actually
modifying the string?  Basically, how can I convince Emacs to display `\"u` as `ü`?

Comment: There's `prettify-symbols-mode`, but that doesn't have support for that particular markup.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you should be able to get prettify-symbols-mode to do this, but I could not figure it out.

Here is a font-lock approach with overlays. It is a little tedious since you have to define every replacement and replacement char, but this is nearly what you have to do with prettify-symbols-mode anyway.

```
(setq replacements '(("\\\"u" . "ü")
             ("\\\"o" . "ö")))

(defun next-symbol (&optional limit)
  (while (re-search-forward (mapconcat
                 (lambda (cc)
                   (concat "\\("
                       (regexp-quote (car cc))
                       "\\)"))
                 replacements "\\|")
                limit t)
    (let* ((pattern (match-string 0))
       (replacement (cdr (assoc pattern replacements)))
       (beg (match-beginning 0))
       (end (match-end 0))
       (ov (make-overlay beg end)))
      (overlay-put ov 'symbol-overlay t)
      (overlay-put ov 'display replacement))))


(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil
 '((next-symbol (0 nil t)))
 t)
```

You can clear the overlays with (ov-clear 'symbol-overlay).